# MultipartFormDataStreamProvider Cleanup

Tags: asp.net

If files are posted to my webapp, then I read them via `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider.FileData`.

I Initialize the provider like this:

```
string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
```

And the provider nicely stores them as "~App_Data/BodyPart_{someguid}"
But how do I clean up those files after I'm done with them?

Comment: How about: `System.IO.File.Delete(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), "BodyPart_{someguid}"));`?

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but I was hoping for something a bit more generic. Something along the lines of DearServer.WouldYouBeSoKindToCleanup(MY_TEMP_DATA); If you catch my drift

Comment: I do. Not sure though if any ready made solution exists. How would it know which files are temp data and which ones are *real* data... Maybe someone else has a suggestion, but if not you can always build it yourself...

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old, but the best way I found to delete the temporary file was after processing it.

```
string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

foreach (var file in provider.Files)
{
    // process file upload...

    // delete temporary file
    System.IO.File.Delete(file.LocalFileName);
}
```

Comment: its strange that no dispose method provided by framework. Your trick works best for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could delete all files that are older than a certain timespan. e.g.

```
private void CleanTempFiles(string dir, int ageInMinutes)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        var time = File.GetCreationTime(file);

        if (time.AddMinutes(ageInMinutes) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it with something like:

```
CleanTempFiles(root, 60); // Delete all files older than 1 hour
```

Comment: Well, since there could be some FileHandle problem, may be there is a way to close the handle manually via PInvoke.